What PnL is realized if swap forwards are realized?
I was reading this question: MtM of interest rate swap if forward rates are realised
I'm confused by the first part of the answer, where user35980 says "So, if forward rates are realized, after one year you will be paying  on a 4y spot swap while the market is , so your MtM on the residual swap will be −>0." So the MtM is positive, so you make money.
However, later on, user says that "if you enter a pay fixed 5y swap today, hold the trade for a year, and then unwind it at market, how much money do you expect to make? The answer is 0. Because the expected value of  , ()= : when you enter the swap, you lock in negative carry of −<0 . When you unwind it at the prevailing 4y rate of  you make −>0".
So the first time, he says that you have a PnL of X-Y, given that the forwards are realized. However, the second paragraph he says that you have a PnL of 0, because the carry and roll cancels out.
What am I missing?

An IRS is a series of unconditional payments. If every rate in the future is realised at exactly the rate at which you priced the mid/market rate of the IRS at the start then all of the forecast cashflows and discount factors will be realised identically. There will be zero PnL.
